# determine the convergence region of a complex series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Determine the region $\Omega$ of the complex plane such that for any $z\in\Omega$ the following series converges:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\exp(\frac{nz}{z-2})$.

I do not know how to treat with complex series. I know $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. Hence I want to use Abel or Dirichlet criterion to determine but I do not know how to solve.

Comment: Do you know what Taylor series are? And do you know the magnitude of complex exponentials? Here's the intuition: if the exponential's argument isn't completely imaginary, then it will keep growing when multiplied by $n$ and exponential growth beats polynomial decay.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Rewrite first $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\exp(\frac{nz}{z-2})$ as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\exp(\frac{z}{z-2})^n$. So, you face an expression which look like  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^2}$ with $x =\exp(\frac{z}{z-2})$

I am sure that you can take from here.

By the way, the summation is just $\text{Li}_2\left(e^{\frac{z}{z-2}}\right)$
,